# Postgres returns different results when bitmap scan disabled

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

When Postgres uses a bitmap heap scan to evaluate a tsquery that includes `!`, it is giving me different results than when it performs a seqscan.

Can anybody shed some light on this? Simply enabling / disabling bitmapscan changes the query results, which feels like a bug to me. Are there any workarounds? I found one for my toy query below (using `NOT`) but for some of the complicated tsquery arguments I have, I'm not sure I can make that work.

```sql
CREATE TABLE examples (content text);
CREATE INDEX ts_idx ON examples USING gin(to_tsvector('simple', content));
INSERT INTO examples VALUES ('Example with a word');

/* Incorrectly returns no results */
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
SET enable_indexscan = OFF;
SET enable_bitmapscan = ON;
SELECT * FROM examples 
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', content) @@ to_tsquery('simple', '!(example<->word)')

/* Correctly returns results */ 
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
SET enable_indexscan = OFF;
SET enable_bitmapscan = OFF; /* disabled */
SELECT * FROM examples 
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', content) @@ to_tsquery('simple', '!(example<->word)')

/* Also correctly returns results by using index and NOT keyword */ 
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
SET enable_indexscan = OFF;
SET enable_bitmapscan = ON; /* enabled */
SELECT * FROM examples 
WHERE NOT to_tsvector('simple', content) @@ to_tsquery('simple', '(example<->word)')

/* Latest version of Postgres 11 */
SELECT VERSION();
/* PostgreSQL 11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, 
compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008, 64-bit */
```

Comment: You would need to include some sample data from the table that shows this. Ideally setup a demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11

Comment: Thanks for the dbfiddle referral @a_horse_with_no_name, that is a neat site.

I actually did include the working repro in the original question though; Postgres core team confirmed it is indeed a bug in Postgres https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/27773.1587773551%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 0):

This was confirmed to be a bug in Postgres <=11.7, <=12.2 and will be fixed in a future minor release, per:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/27773.1587773551%40sss.pgh.pa.us

With candidate patch:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16254.1587852873%40sss.pgh.pa.us